# My PDO query will not work properly and is failing

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have the following PDO query and it's not working properly. When submitting a blog post twice (submit, refresh, submit), sometimes it will not process the query and save the data into my database. This is kind of a strange behavior and I have never experienced something like it. I'm used to using MySQLI so i'm not completely sure if the query is wrong or if it's something else. However, here is the code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $owner = $user->fetchColumn();
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    $is_saved = $_POST["is_saved"];
    $sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `job`) VALUES (:name1,:job1);';
    $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $preparedStatement->execute(array(':name1' => $title, ':job1' => $content));
    if($preparedStatement)
    {
        $LastID = $db->lastInsertId();
        $success = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $error = '';
    }

}
```

If it's not in the code, what can possible cause this?

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Maybe numbers are not allowed in parameter name(wild guess)?

Comment: Probably the number thing but also try doing the queries with try catch blocks too

Comment: Hm.. Numbers don't seems to be the issue in this case @Mihai

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't get any errors, unfortunately. Query is still behaving weird. Sometimes it inserts the content, and sometimes not. Tried with MySQLI prepared statements and the same happens.

Comment: Maybe this is a Plesk/MySQL issue and not the PHP itself?